# Subtracting two matrices with MKL

Tags: c++, intel-mkl

I am unable to find out which function to use in MKL for subtracting two 1D matrices (ex. Y = A - B).

I went over the documentation related to multiplying matrices (http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/mkl_sa/11/tutorials/mkl_mmx_c/GUID-36BFBCE9-EB0A-43B0-ADAF-2B65275726EA.htm) but there doesn't seem to be any addition/subtraction examples out there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For dense matrices you always allocate matrices as a vector of length `n*m`, therefore you use the corresponding BLAS Level 1 routines, e.g.: `SAXPY(N,SA,SX,INCX,SY,INCY) <==> y = alpha*x+y`